# go get throws 'fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution'

Tags: golang

I am trying to build from source of [hugo](https://gitter.im/spf13/hugo) on osx. I have set `GOPATH` to the the hugo git clone directory. Then `go get` throws the following error message:

```
> go get                                                                                                                                

go build github.com/spf13/cobra: /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/compile: signal: segmentation fault
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0xb01dfacedebac1e pc=0x17cc70]

goroutine 10 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x689a00, 0x2a)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:547 +0x90 fp=0xc8205232b8 sp=0xc8205232a0
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:12 +0x5a fp=0xc820523308 sp=0xc8205232b8
sync.(*Pool).Get(0x882700, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/sync/pool.go:102 +0x40 fp=0xc820523358 sp=0xc820523308
fmt.newPrinter(0x464d20)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:133 +0x27 fp=0xc820523398 sp=0xc820523358
fmt.Sprintf(0x5f4230, 0xf, 0xc8205234c0, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:202 +0x2b fp=0xc8205233e8 sp=0xc820523398
fmt.Errorf(0x5f4230, 0xf, 0xc8205234c0, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/fmt/print.go:212 +0x65 fp=0xc820523450 sp=0xc8205233e8
main.(*builder).build.func1(0xc820523e00, 0xc820419380)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1352 +0x1ad fp=0xc8205234e8 sp=0xc820523450
main.(*builder).build(0xc820158f50, 0xc820419380, 0x9bd028, 0xc8204591a0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1492 +0x23c1 fp=0xc820523df0 sp=0xc8205234e8
main.(*builder).do.func1(0xc820419380)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1257 +0x3b2 fp=0xc820523eb0 sp=0xc820523df0
main.(*builder).do.func2(0xc820458ae0, 0xc820158f50, 0xc8202e30e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1314 +0x156 fp=0xc820523f88 sp=0xc820523eb0
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1 fp=0xc820523f90 sp=0xc820523f88
created by main.(*builder).do
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1320 +0x39e

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc820458aec)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/runtime/sema.go:47 +0x26
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc820458ae0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/sync/waitgroup.go:127 +0xb4
main.(*builder).do(0xc820158f50, 0xc8201521a0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1323 +0x3c6
main.runInstall(0x888fe0, 0xc820283ed0, 0x1, 0x1)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:634 +0x4e5
main.runGet(0x888fe0, 0xc820283ed0, 0x1, 0x1)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/get.go:141 +0x441
main.main()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/main.go:181 +0x783

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1

goroutine 5 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:116 +0x132
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x18
created by os/signal.init.1
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x37

goroutine 7 [runnable]:
syscall.Syscall6(0x7, 0x16d01, 0xc820524dcc, 0x0, 0xc8203fe870, 0x0, 0x0, 0x16d01, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:41 +0x5
syscall.wait4(0x16d01, 0xc820524dcc, 0x0, 0xc8203fe870, 0x90, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:34 +0x7f
syscall.Wait4(0x16d01, 0xc820524e14, 0x0, 0xc8203fe870, 0xc8201bc200, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_bsd.go:129 +0x55
os.(*Process).wait(0xc82048ad80, 0x54, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec_unix.go:22 +0x105
os.(*Process).Wait(0xc82048ad80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/doc.go:49 +0x2d
os/exec.(*Cmd).Wait(0xc82015aa00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:396 +0x211
os/exec.(*Cmd).Run(0xc82015aa00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:262 +0x64
main.(*builder).runOut(0xc820158f50, 0xc82024ae40, 0x39, 0xc820497141, 0x18, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc820513080, 0x10, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2049 +0x364
main.gcToolchain.gc(0xc820158f50, 0xc8202de000, 0xc8203c0d80, 0x5d, 0xc8200193b0, 0x61, 0x0, 0xc8203acd00, 0x4, 0x4, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2310 +0x1261
main.(*gcToolchain).gc(0x8acf60, 0xc820158f50, 0xc8202de000, 0xc8203c0d80, 0x5d, 0xc8200193b0, 0x61, 0x0, 0xc8203acd00, 0x4, ...)
    <autogenerated>:3 +0x18e
main.(*builder).build(0xc820158f50, 0xc8204185b0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1484 +0x224c
main.(*builder).do.func1(0xc8204185b0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1257 +0x3b2
main.(*builder).do.func2(0xc820458ae0, 0xc820158f50, 0xc8202e30e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1314 +0x156
created by main.(*builder).do
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1320 +0x39e

goroutine 8 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall6(0x7, 0x16d00, 0xc82052edcc, 0x0, 0xc8203fe7e0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc82052eda8, 0xdef30, 0xc82052eda0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:41 +0x5
syscall.wait4(0x16d00, 0xc82052edcc, 0x0, 0xc8203fe7e0, 0x90, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:34 +0x7f
syscall.Wait4(0x16d00, 0xc82052ee14, 0x0, 0xc8203fe7e0, 0xc8201bc1c8, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_bsd.go:129 +0x55
os.(*Process).wait(0xc82048a5c0, 0x54, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec_unix.go:22 +0x105
os.(*Process).Wait(0xc82048a5c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/doc.go:49 +0x2d
os/exec.(*Cmd).Wait(0xc82015a8c0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:396 +0x211
os/exec.(*Cmd).Run(0xc82015a8c0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:262 +0x64
main.(*builder).runOut(0xc820158f50, 0xc8202f5000, 0x3d, 0xc8204971e1, 0x1c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc8201c9600, 0x18, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2049 +0x364
main.gcToolchain.gc(0xc820158f50, 0xc820117c00, 0xc820192230, 0x61, 0xc820192150, 0x65, 0x0, 0xc8203ac480, 0x4, 0x4, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2310 +0x1261
main.(*gcToolchain).gc(0x8acf60, 0xc820158f50, 0xc820117c00, 0xc820192230, 0x61, 0xc820192150, 0x65, 0x0, 0xc8203ac480, 0x4, ...)
    <autogenerated>:3 +0x18e
main.(*builder).build(0xc820158f50, 0xc820418b60, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1484 +0x224c
main.(*builder).do.func1(0xc820418b60)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1257 +0x3b2
main.(*builder).do.func2(0xc820458ae0, 0xc820158f50, 0xc8202e30e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1314 +0x156
created by main.(*builder).do
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1320 +0x39e

goroutine 9 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall6(0x7, 0x16cec, 0xc820528dcc, 0x0, 0xc8202fc6c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc820528da8, 0xdef30, 0xc820528da0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:41 +0x5
syscall.wait4(0x16cec, 0xc820528dcc, 0x0, 0xc8202fc6c0, 0x90, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:34 +0x7f
syscall.Wait4(0x16cec, 0xc820528e14, 0x0, 0xc8202fc6c0, 0xc82029a0d0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_bsd.go:129 +0x55
os.(*Process).wait(0xc8203dc0a0, 0x54, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec_unix.go:22 +0x105
os.(*Process).Wait(0xc8203dc0a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/doc.go:49 +0x2d
os/exec.(*Cmd).Wait(0xc8201fc3c0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:396 +0x211
os/exec.(*Cmd).Run(0xc8201fc3c0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:262 +0x64
main.(*builder).runOut(0xc820158f50, 0xc820411b00, 0x3f, 0xc8203a0ee1, 0x1e, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc8202d2420, 0x15, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2049 +0x364
main.gcToolchain.gc(0xc820158f50, 0xc820467c00, 0xc820175260, 0x63, 0xc820175110, 0x67, 0x0, 0xc82044fac0, 0x4, 0x4, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2310 +0x1261
main.(*gcToolchain).gc(0x8acf60, 0xc820158f50, 0xc820467c00, 0xc820175260, 0x63, 0xc820175110, 0x67, 0x0, 0xc82044fac0, 0x4, ...)
    <autogenerated>:3 +0x18e
main.(*builder).build(0xc820158f50, 0xc820238680, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1484 +0x224c
main.(*builder).do.func1(0xc820238680)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1257 +0x3b2
main.(*builder).do.func2(0xc820458ae0, 0xc820158f50, 0xc8202e30e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1314 +0x156
created by main.(*builder).do
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1320 +0x39e

goroutine 11 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall6(0x7, 0x16cff, 0xc820526dcc, 0x0, 0xc8203fe750, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc820526da8, 0xdef30, 0xc820526da0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:41 +0x5
syscall.wait4(0x16cff, 0xc820526dcc, 0x0, 0xc8203fe750, 0x90, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:34 +0x7f
syscall.Wait4(0x16cff, 0xc820526e14, 0x0, 0xc8203fe750, 0xc8201bc190, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_bsd.go:129 +0x55
os.(*Process).wait(0xc820293e80, 0x54, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec_unix.go:22 +0x105
os.(*Process).Wait(0xc820293e80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/doc.go:49 +0x2d
os/exec.(*Cmd).Wait(0xc82015a780, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:396 +0x211
os/exec.(*Cmd).Run(0xc82015a780, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:262 +0x64
main.(*builder).runOut(0xc820158f50, 0xc8201354f0, 0x43, 0xc8202646c1, 0x22, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc820512b00, 0xd, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2049 +0x364
main.gcToolchain.gc(0xc820158f50, 0xc8204a9c00, 0xc8201927e0, 0x67, 0xc820192620, 0x6b, 0x0, 0xc8202937e0, 0x2, 0x2, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2310 +0x1261
main.(*gcToolchain).gc(0x8acf60, 0xc820158f50, 0xc8204a9c00, 0xc8201927e0, 0x67, 0xc820192620, 0x6b, 0x0, 0xc8202937e0, 0x2, ...)
    <autogenerated>:3 +0x18e
main.(*builder).build(0xc820158f50, 0xc820418d00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1484 +0x224c
main.(*builder).do.func1(0xc820418d00)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1257 +0x3b2
main.(*builder).do.func2(0xc820458ae0, 0xc820158f50, 0xc8202e30e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1314 +0x156
created by main.(*builder).do
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1320 +0x39e

goroutine 12 [runnable]:
syscall.Syscall6(0x7, 0x16d02, 0xc82053edcc, 0x0, 0xc8202fd3b0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x16d02, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:41 +0x5
syscall.wait4(0x16d02, 0xc82053edcc, 0x0, 0xc8202fd3b0, 0x90, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:34 +0x7f
syscall.Wait4(0x16d02, 0xc82053ee14, 0x0, 0xc8202fd3b0, 0xc82029a3a8, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_bsd.go:129 +0x55
os.(*Process).wait(0xc820312cc0, 0x54, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec_unix.go:22 +0x105
os.(*Process).Wait(0xc820312cc0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/doc.go:49 +0x2d
os/exec.(*Cmd).Wait(0xc8201fdb80, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:396 +0x211
os/exec.(*Cmd).Run(0xc8201fdb80, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:262 +0x64
main.(*builder).runOut(0xc820158f50, 0xc8202c3a00, 0x31, 0xc8204972a1, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc8205b0dc0, 0x19, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2049 +0x364
main.gcToolchain.gc(0xc820158f50, 0xc82040e400, 0xc8204c22a0, 0x55, 0xc8204c2120, 0x59, 0x0, 0xc820312520, 0x2, 0x2, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2310 +0x1261
main.(*gcToolchain).gc(0x8acf60, 0xc820158f50, 0xc82040e400, 0xc8204c22a0, 0x55, 0xc8204c2120, 0x59, 0x0, 0xc820312520, 0x2, ...)
    <autogenerated>:3 +0x18e
main.(*builder).build(0xc820158f50, 0xc820418ea0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1484 +0x224c
main.(*builder).do.func1(0xc820418ea0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1257 +0x3b2
main.(*builder).do.func2(0xc820458ae0, 0xc820158f50, 0xc8202e30e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1314 +0x156
created by main.(*builder).do
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1320 +0x39e

goroutine 13 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall6(0x7, 0x16cea, 0xc82052adcc, 0x0, 0xc8203fe2d0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc82052ada8, 0xdef30, 0xc82052ada0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:41 +0x5
syscall.wait4(0x16cea, 0xc82052adcc, 0x0, 0xc8203fe2d0, 0x90, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:34 +0x7f
syscall.Wait4(0x16cea, 0xc82052ae14, 0x0, 0xc8203fe2d0, 0xc8201bc078, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_bsd.go:129 +0x55
os.(*Process).wait(0xc820405680, 0x54, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec_unix.go:22 +0x105
os.(*Process).Wait(0xc820405680, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/doc.go:49 +0x2d
os/exec.(*Cmd).Wait(0xc82015a140, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:396 +0x211
os/exec.(*Cmd).Run(0xc82015a140, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:262 +0x64
main.(*builder).runOut(0xc820158f50, 0xc820226e80, 0x3b, 0xc8201f6a21, 0x1a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc8205122c0, 0x15, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2049 +0x364
main.gcToolchain.gc(0xc820158f50, 0xc82040e000, 0xc8203eb9e0, 0x5f, 0xc820175030, 0x63, 0x0, 0xc820404e40, 0x2, 0x2, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2310 +0x1261
main.(*gcToolchain).gc(0x8acf60, 0xc820158f50, 0xc82040e000, 0xc8203eb9e0, 0x5f, 0xc820175030, 0x63, 0x0, 0xc820404e40, 0x2, ...)
    <autogenerated>:3 +0x18e
main.(*builder).build(0xc820158f50, 0xc820454a90, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1484 +0x224c
main.(*builder).do.func1(0xc820454a90)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1257 +0x3b2
main.(*builder).do.func2(0xc820458ae0, 0xc820158f50, 0xc8202e30e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1314 +0x156
created by main.(*builder).do
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1320 +0x39e

goroutine 14 [runnable]:
syscall.Syscall(0x6, 0xd, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:16 +0x5
syscall.Close(0xd, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:404 +0x4a
syscall.forkExec(0xc820431900, 0x40, 0xc820211100, 0x10, 0x10, 0xc82053acf8, 0x16d06, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/exec_unix.go:201 +0x540
syscall.StartProcess(0xc820431900, 0x40, 0xc820211100, 0x10, 0x10, 0xc82053acf8, 0x2, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/exec_unix.go:240 +0x6b
os.startProcess(0xc820431900, 0x40, 0xc820211100, 0x10, 0x10, 0xc82053af30, 0x5c6b00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec_posix.go:45 +0x33e
os.StartProcess(0xc820431900, 0x40, 0xc820211100, 0x10, 0x10, 0xc82053af30, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/doc.go:28 +0x69
os/exec.(*Cmd).Start(0xc82040c500, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:332 +0x761
os/exec.(*Cmd).Run(0xc82040c500, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:259 +0x2d
main.(*builder).runOut(0xc820158f50, 0xc82024b040, 0x37, 0xc820405361, 0x16, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc82032a840, 0xd, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2049 +0x364
main.gcToolchain.gc(0xc820158f50, 0xc82043f800, 0xc8204c3440, 0x5b, 0xc8204c3380, 0x5f, 0x0, 0xc8202d6180, 0x2, 0x2, ...)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:2310 +0x1261
main.(*gcToolchain).gc(0x8acf60, 0xc820158f50, 0xc82043f800, 0xc8204c3440, 0x5b, 0xc8204c3380, 0x5f, 0x0, 0xc8202d6180, 0x2, ...)
    <autogenerated>:3 +0x18e
main.(*builder).build(0xc820158f50, 0xc820419520, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1484 +0x224c
main.(*builder).do.func1(0xc820419520)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1257 +0x3b2
main.(*builder).do.func2(0xc820458ae0, 0xc820158f50, 0xc8202e30e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1314 +0x156
created by main.(*builder).do
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/cmd/go/build.go:1320 +0x39e

goroutine 42 [runnable]:
syscall.Syscall(0x3, 0x9, 0xc8205b2a00, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:16 +0x5
syscall.read(0x9, 0xc8205b2a00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:972 +0x5f
syscall.Read(0x9, 0xc8205b2a00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go:161 +0x4d
os.(*File).read(0xc8201bc1c0, 0xc8205b2a00, 0x200, 0x200, 0xc8205b2a00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file_unix.go:228 +0x75
os.(*File).Read(0xc8201bc1c0, 0xc8205b2a00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file.go:95 +0x8a
bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom(0xc8205c44d0, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc1c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/bytes/buffer.go:176 +0x23f
io.copyBuffer(0xd53f50, 0xc8205c44d0, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc1c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/io/io.go:374 +0x180
io.Copy(0xd53f50, 0xc8205c44d0, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc1c0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/io/io.go:350 +0x64
os/exec.(*Cmd).writerDescriptor.func1(0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:236 +0x8b
os/exec.(*Cmd).Start.func1(0xc82015a8c0, 0xc82048a0a0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:344 +0x1d
created by os/exec.(*Cmd).Start
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:345 +0x967

goroutine 116 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall(0x3, 0x4, 0xc8202c0800, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x9e679)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:16 +0x5
syscall.read(0x4, 0xc8202c0800, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:972 +0x5f
syscall.Read(0x4, 0xc8202c0800, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go:161 +0x4d
os.(*File).read(0xc82029a0c8, 0xc8202c0800, 0x200, 0x200, 0xc8202c0800, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file_unix.go:228 +0x75
os.(*File).Read(0xc82029a0c8, 0xc8202c0800, 0x200, 0x200, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file.go:95 +0x8a
bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom(0xc8204eb570, 0xd442a8, 0xc82029a0c8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/bytes/buffer.go:176 +0x23f
io.copyBuffer(0xd53f50, 0xc8204eb570, 0xd442a8, 0xc82029a0c8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/io/io.go:374 +0x180
io.Copy(0xd53f50, 0xc8204eb570, 0xd442a8, 0xc82029a0c8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/io/io.go:350 +0x64
os/exec.(*Cmd).writerDescriptor.func1(0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:236 +0x8b
os/exec.(*Cmd).Start.func1(0xc8201fc3c0, 0xc820103b00)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:344 +0x1d
created by os/exec.(*Cmd).Start
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:345 +0x967

goroutine 129 [runnable]:
syscall.Syscall(0x6, 0xe, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:16 +0x5
syscall.Close(0xe, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:404 +0x4a
os.(*file).close(0xc820312640, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file_unix.go:140 +0x61
os.(*File).Close(0xc82029a3a0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file_unix.go:132 +0x54
os/exec.(*Cmd).writerDescriptor.func1(0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:237 +0xad
os/exec.(*Cmd).Start.func1(0xc8201fdb80, 0xc8203126a0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:344 +0x1d
created by os/exec.(*Cmd).Start
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:345 +0x967

goroutine 36 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall(0x3, 0xb, 0xc8204ec400, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x9e679)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:16 +0x5
syscall.read(0xb, 0xc8204ec400, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:972 +0x5f
syscall.Read(0xb, 0xc8204ec400, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go:161 +0x4d
os.(*File).read(0xc8201bc070, 0xc8204ec400, 0x200, 0x200, 0xc8204ec400, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file_unix.go:228 +0x75
os.(*File).Read(0xc8201bc070, 0xc8204ec400, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file.go:95 +0x8a
bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom(0xc8203045b0, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc070, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/bytes/buffer.go:176 +0x23f
io.copyBuffer(0xd53f50, 0xc8203045b0, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc070, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/io/io.go:374 +0x180
io.Copy(0xd53f50, 0xc8203045b0, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc070, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/io/io.go:350 +0x64
os/exec.(*Cmd).writerDescriptor.func1(0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:236 +0x8b
os/exec.(*Cmd).Start.func1(0xc82015a140, 0xc820405000)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:344 +0x1d
created by os/exec.(*Cmd).Start
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:345 +0x967

goroutine 41 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall(0x3, 0xa, 0xc8205a8a00, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x9e679)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:16 +0x5
syscall.read(0xa, 0xc8205a8a00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:972 +0x5f
syscall.Read(0xa, 0xc8205a8a00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go:161 +0x4d
os.(*File).read(0xc8201bc188, 0xc8205a8a00, 0x200, 0x200, 0xc8205a8a00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file_unix.go:228 +0x75
os.(*File).Read(0xc8201bc188, 0xc8205a8a00, 0x200, 0x200, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file.go:95 +0x8a
bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom(0xc820305f10, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc188, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/bytes/buffer.go:176 +0x23f
io.copyBuffer(0xd53f50, 0xc820305f10, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc188, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/io/io.go:374 +0x180
io.Copy(0xd53f50, 0xc820305f10, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc188, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/io/io.go:350 +0x64
os/exec.(*Cmd).writerDescriptor.func1(0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:236 +0x8b
os/exec.(*Cmd).Start.func1(0xc82015a780, 0xc820293960)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:344 +0x1d
created by os/exec.(*Cmd).Start
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:345 +0x967

goroutine 43 [runnable]:
syscall.Syscall(0x3, 0x8, 0xc820173aa2, 0x35e, 0x66, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:16 +0x5
syscall.read(0x8, 0xc820173aa2, 0x35e, 0x35e, 0x3b, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:972 +0x5f
syscall.Read(0x8, 0xc820173aa2, 0x35e, 0x35e, 0x3b, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go:161 +0x4d
os.(*File).read(0xc8201bc1f8, 0xc820173aa2, 0x35e, 0x35e, 0x3b, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file_unix.go:228 +0x75
os.(*File).Read(0xc8201bc1f8, 0xc820173aa2, 0x35e, 0x35e, 0x3b, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/file.go:95 +0x8a
bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom(0xc8205c4b60, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc1f8, 0xaa2, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/bytes/buffer.go:176 +0x23f
io.copyBuffer(0xd53f50, 0xc8205c4b60, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc1f8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/io/io.go:374 +0x180
io.Copy(0xd53f50, 0xc8205c4b60, 0xd442a8, 0xc8201bc1f8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/io/io.go:350 +0x64
os/exec.(*Cmd).writerDescriptor.func1(0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:236 +0x8b
os/exec.(*Cmd).Start.func1(0xc82015aa00, 0xc82048a820)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:344 +0x1d
created by os/exec.(*Cmd).Start
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6.3/libexec/src/os/exec/exec.go:345 +0x967
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, when my "go build" failed with signal 11 ( bad access). I guess it started after updating to new OSX version. I removed 1.6.3 which is the latest version available from homebrew and installed most recent version ( 1.7.3 ) from [golang home website](https://golang.org/dl/) and everything started to build normally.